# How to choose multiple files using File Upload Control?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a file upload control.Now on clicking on that, I want to select multiple files.

How can I do so?

Comment: @Basic - The irony. 1 year later I've googled 'asp.net file upload multiple' and your comment means this comes up top.

Comment: @Rudi Sorry! At least I gave three good links...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [`FileUpload.AllowMultiple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.allowmultiple(v=vs.110).aspx) property in **.NET 4.5 and higher** will allow you the control to select multiple files.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileImages" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
```

.NET 4 and below

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fileImages" Multiple="Multiple" runat="server" />
```

On the post-back, you can then:

```
 Dim flImages As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files                   
 For Each key As String In flImages.Keys
    Dim flfile As HttpPostedFile = flImages(key)
    flfile.SaveAs(yourpath & flfile.FileName)
 Next
```

Comment: what is the `flBanner`?

Comment: The `for each key as String` loop did not work for me (it listed the same FileName over and over), but using an index based loop with `For i = 0 To uploadedFiles.Count - 1` did.

Comment: As I go through each file, can I view the content of the file? Btw I am trying this in C#

Answer (score 29):

here is the complete example of how you can select and upload multiple files in asp.net 
using file upload control....

write this code in .aspx file..

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <input type="file" id="myfile" multiple="multiple" name="myfile" runat="server" size="100" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Span1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

after that write this code in .aspx.cs file..

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) {
          string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\Upload");
          HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
          Span1.Text = string.Empty;

          for(int i = 0;i < uploadedFiles.Count;i++) {
              HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

              try {
                  if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0) {
                     Span1.Text += "<u>File #" + (i + 1) +  "</u><br>";
                     Span1.Text += "File Content Type: " +  userPostedFile.ContentType      + "<br>";
                     Span1.Text += "File Size: " + userPostedFile.ContentLength           + "kb<br>";
                     Span1.Text += "File Name: " + userPostedFile.FileName + "<br>";

                     userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" +    Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));                  
                     Span1.Text += "Location where saved: " +   filepath + "\\" +   Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName) + "<p>";
                  }
              } catch(Exception Ex) {
                  Span1.Text += "Error: <br>" + Ex.Message;
              }
           }
        }
    }
```

and here you go...your multiple file upload control is ready..have a happy day.

Comment: This piece of code is great thanks. However HttpPostedFile.ContentLength is expressed in bytes, not in kilobits...

Answer (score 7):

```
        aspx code

            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick ="UploadMultipleFiles" accept ="image/gif, image/jpeg" />
            <hr />
            <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" ForeColor ="Green" />


    Code Behind:

protected void UploadMultipleFiles(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
     {
          string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
          postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fileName);
     }
     lblSuccess.Text = string.Format("{0} files have been uploaded successfully.", FileUpload1.PostedFiles.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

step 1: add

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" id="fileUpload1" Multiple="Multiple">
    </asp:FileUpload>
```

step 2: add

```
Protected Sub uploadBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles uploadBtn.Click
    Dim ImageFiles As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
    For i As Integer = 0 To ImageFiles.Count - 1
        Dim file As HttpPostedFile = ImageFiles(i)
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads/") & ImageFiles(i).FileName)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There are other options you can use these controls which have multiple upload options and these controls have also Ajax support

1) [Flajxian](http://flajaxianfileupload.codeplex.com/)
2) [Valums](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader)
3) [Subgurim FileUpload](http://en.fileuploadajax.subgurim.net/)

Answer (score 2):

**default.aspx code**

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" id="fileUpload1" Multiple="Multiple">
        </asp:FileUpload>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Upload Files" id="uploadBtn"/>
```

**default.aspx.vb**

```
Protected Sub uploadBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles uploadBtn.Click
    Dim ImageFiles As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
    For i As Integer = 0 To ImageFiles.Count - 1
    Dim file As HttpPostedFile = ImageFiles(i)
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads/") & file.FileName) 
    Next       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To add multiple files use below code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .fileUpload{
    width:255px;    
    font-size:11px;
    color:#000000;
    border:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#7f9db9;    
    height:17px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div id="fileUploadarea"><asp:FileUpload ID="fuPuzzleImage" runat="server" CssClass="fileUpload" /><br /></div><br />
    <div><input style="display:block;" id="btnAddMoreFiles" type="button" value="Add more images" onclick="AddMoreImages();" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function AddMoreImages() {
            if (!document.getElementById && !document.createElement)
                return false;
            var fileUploadarea = document.getElementById("fileUploadarea");
            if (!fileUploadarea)
                return false;
            var newLine = document.createElement("br");
            fileUploadarea.appendChild(newLine);
            var newFile = document.createElement("input");
            newFile.type = "file";
            newFile.setAttribute("class", "fileUpload");

            if (!AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId)
                AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId = 100;
            newFile.setAttribute("id", "FileUpload" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
            newFile.setAttribute("name", "FileUpload" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.appendChild(newFile);
            div.setAttribute("id", "div" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
            fileUploadarea.appendChild(div);
            AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId++;
        }

    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Server side code:

```
try
{
    HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
    for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
        {                        
            hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/") +System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);                        
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The FileUpload.AllowMultiple property in .NET 4.5 and higher will allow you the control to select multiple files.

Below 4.5 like 4.0(vs 2010) we can use jquery for multiple file upload in single control,using,2 js files:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js and http://code.google.com/p/jquery-multifile-plugin/

in aspx file upload tag,add like class="multi"

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" class="multi" runat="server" />
```

If you want working example go to [link](http://kuttyrajesh.blogspot.in/2016/02/multiple-file-upload-in-fileupload.html) download sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
        Dim PathName As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
            Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = hfc(i)

            If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
                hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/E:\") & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName))
                PathName = Server.MapPath(hpf.FileName)

                If j < hfc.Count Then
                    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conString").ConnectionString
                    Dim sqlquery As String
                    sqlquery = "Insert_proc"
                    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlquery, con)

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PathName
                    j = j + 1

                    Try
                        con.Open()
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Throw ex
                    Finally
                        con.Close()
                        con.Dispose()

                    End Try
                    If j = hfc.Count Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next

    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception

        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I just come across this brilliantly simple solution if you are using .Net 4.5 (not supported this easily in lower versions) and you can use jQuery to make things really simple and painless.

[Uploading Multiple Files Using jQuery and Generic Handler in ASP.Net 4.5](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/uploading-multiple-files-using-jquery-and-generic-handler-in/)

Of course there is the commercial version for classic ASP which can be found at [ASP Uploader](http://www.aspuploader.com)

Answer (score -3):

Why not use flash & javascript upload control?

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/