# asp:FileUpload in ASP.Net 3.5 is not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-upload

I am using asp.net 3.5 version. In a single page I have 5 **asp:FileUpload** controls.

I have tried using the following code:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/");
string filename = "";
string extension = "";
int fcount = 1;
HttpFileCollection HFC = Request.Files;

for (int c = 0; c < HFC.Count; c++)
{
  HttpPostedFile HPF = HFC[c];
  if (HPF.ContentLength < 2100000)  //2,100,000 bytes (approximately 2 MB)
  {
     extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(HPF.FileName);
     filename = "ML" + MyId + fcount + extension;
     HPF.SaveAs(path + "\\" + filename);
  }
  fcount++;
  DBimg = filename + ",";
}
```

As it has 5 different upload control I am not getting the values for a single control. I need to save files that has been selected separately from those upload controls into separate folders. From **HPF** how can I get different controls.Is there any way out??

P.N. - In asp.net 3.5 file upload controls for multiple selection doesn't provide MyUploader1.PostedFiles instead it provide MyUploader1.PostedFile

Please help me out...Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to upload multiple files from a single file upload control then set the FileUpload.AllowMultiple property to true (this only works in .NET 4.5). This is discussed further in this question:
[How to choose multiple files using File Upload Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441925/how-to-choose-multiple-files-using-file-upload-control)

If you're looking at uploading multiple files from multiple file upload controls on a single page, then you will need to extract the file from each individual uploader. For example:

```
if(firstUploader.HasFile)
{
    HttpPostedFile firstFile = firstUploader.PostedFile;
    firstFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/FirstUploaderContent/" + firstFile.FileName);
}

if(secondUploader.HasFile)
{
    HttpPostedFile secondFile = secondUploader.PostedFile;
    secondFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/SecondUploaderContent/" + secondFile.FileName);
}

// Handle further files here ...
```

Comment: But will it work for multiple upload also for each file uploader? All the uploader I have on that page should work for multiple uploads. I will check the code and will definitely let you know. Thanks @ACOMIT001