# How to upload multiple files using multiple fileupload controls in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, .net-4.0, multiple-file-upload

I have a webpage(.aspx) which contains MULTIPLE `FileUpload` controls.

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadPort" runat="server" CssClass="Upload"  Multiple="Multiple"/>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadSearchImages" runat="server" CssClass="Upload"  Multiple="Multiple"/>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string filenm = string.Empty;
       HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
       for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
       {
           HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
           if (uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
              string filename = uploadfile.FileName;
              string imgFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminSearchImgFolderPath"];
              System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(uploadfile.InputStream); 
              image.Save(imgFolder + "\\" + GetSearchImageFileName("TEST"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);

             }
        }
    }
```

Here, `Request.Files` will get collectively all files from both the `FileUploadControls`.

I am **NOT able to IDENTIFY which file(s) are from specific FileUpload control**?

***I know its possible in 4.5 but my current framework is 4.0 and i dont want to upgrade to 4.5. Any solution using existing 4.0 framework??***

Help appreciated!

**Please note:** This is not DUPLICATE question as my requirement is to upload and identify the files of different fileupload controls on single page.

Comment: Use if (FileUploadPort.HasFiles) to determine if the control has files and then continue to save the files. The process you can implement for the other fileupload control. This way you are able to identify which files are from a specific fileupload control.

Comment: This i have tried but how to get/iterate to files of specific fileupload control? Will you please post some code here...?????

Comment: Use this link. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-multiple-files-with-ASPNet-45-FileUpload-control-in-Visual-Studio-2012-and-2013.aspx

Comment: Please read the post carefully. I have mentioned i am using 4.0 and not 4.5 framework :(

Comment: :) Ok, Take a look at this link, that might work for you. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667604/Upload-multiple-files-in-asp-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose multiple files using File Upload Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441925/how-to-choose-multiple-files-using-file-upload-control)

Comment: Please read the question carefully..! it is 'Multiple file upload using multiple File Upload Controls' not single 'FileUpload control'

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extension method to get the same effect as .Net 4.5 as in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30360786

[ note: I can't comment that's why i posted this as an answer ]