# c# adding multiple files to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am working on a simple code to upload multiple files using single upload button `(AllowMultiple="true")`, and I am trying to add all the uploaded files to list, but the problem is only the first file is added without the other files.

asp.net

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="file1" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

c#

```
PdfReader pdfReader1 = new PdfReader(file1.PostedFile.InputStream);
List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();
readerList.Add(pdfReader1);
```

Comment: That's because you have added one reader to you reader list. You probably want to read files with reader.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441925/how-to-choose-multiple-files-using-file-upload-control

Comment: First, AllowMultiple="true" is a .Net 4.5 property. Are you sure to have it ? Below 4.5 it was something like Multiple="Multiple" (check on the MSDN). Second : you have to use the file1.PostedFiles collection to retrieve all files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With  `PostedFile` you get only one item, use `PostedFiles` instead:

```
List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();
readerList.AddRange(file1.PostedFiles.Select(f=>new PdfReader(f.InputStream)))
```

Comment: OP: Make sure to close/dispose the readers after you are done with them.