# How to Save multiple files in asp.net 4.0 by Fileupload1 Control with multiple fileupload2 control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

How to Save multiple files in asp.net 4.0 by Fileupload Control with multiple fileupload control?
 I have two fileupload control one for image and second for thumbimage. So I want to save multiple image and thumbimage ?

Comment: HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles =Request.Files;
  int i = uploadedFiles.Count;  if (i > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {

                HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[j];

Comment: How to identity file fileupload1 and fileupload2 files.

Comment: HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;      how to get seprately fileupload1 and fileupload2 in filecollection

Comment: Can you show your markup and backend code

Comment: <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" class="form-control"  multiple="multiple" AllowMultiple="True" runat="server" />

 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" class="form-control"  multiple="multiple" AllowMultiple="True" runat="server" />


 HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles =Request.Files;
       
        int i = uploadedFiles.Count;

if (i > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {

                HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[j];
   int r = image.Add(userPostedFile.FileName);
}
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose multiple files using File Upload Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441925/how-to-choose-multiple-files-using-file-upload-control)

Comment: Not dupliate . i need to upload two multiple fileupload control

Answer (score 0):

You are actually overwriting the fist file with the second one when you are in the loop. I would suggest you to create a list for the files and add to the list in the loop like below. You will then have a list of file when you can use firstOrDefault() for the first item as well as use Skip() and Take() to select any item you want.

```
HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
List<HttpPostedFile> fileList1 = new List<HttpPostedFile>();
List<HttpPostedFile> fileList2 = new List<HttpPostedFile>();



for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile hpf = uploadedFiles[i];
    var hpfKey = uploadedFiles.Keys[i];
    if (hpfKey.IndexOf("FileUpload1") > 0)
    {
        fileList1.Add(hpf);
    }
    if (hpfKey.IndexOf("FileUpload2") > 0)
    {
        fileList2.Add(hpf);
    }
}
```

Update:

Now to get the first file you call FirstOrDefault() on the list like below:

```
 fileList1.FirstOrDefault();
```

And to get the second file :

```
fileList1.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;  how to get only fileupload1 postedfile

Comment: No  I have two multiple file upload control like fileupload1 and file upload2.So I want to get  HttpFileCollection uploadfiles=Request.Files only for fileupload1 not fileupload2 also

Comment: Sorry sir PostedFiles is not supported asp.net 4.0 .

Comment: Ok, with that it  becomes a bit more complicated but I have updated my answer which should just work now.

Answer (score 0):

HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;

```
    int i = uploadedFiles.Count;


    List<HttpPostedFile> fileList1 = new List<HttpPostedFile>();
    List<HttpPostedFile> fileList2 = new List<HttpPostedFile>();

    if (i > 0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i/2; j++)
        {
            fileList1.Add(uploadedFiles[j]);
        }
    }

    if (i > 0)
    {
        for (int j = i / 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            fileList2.Add(uploadedFiles[j]);
        }
    }

    int filecount = fileList1.Count;
   if (filecount > 0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < filecount; j++)
        {
     string image =  fileList1[j].FileName;
    fileList1[j].SaveAs(imagepath);
    string image =  fileList2[j].FileName;
    fileList2[j].SaveAs(imagepath);
    }
   }
```