# The original file is in the temp folder error when uploading a file to IIS server from asp.net web forms project

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to upload some files  wtih different extensions like .png,.jpg,.txt,.pdf  etc. to IIS server .However my all files  are created to given path but they are all 1kb size and when you open them it says

> The original file is in the temp folder. Full path of the file:
>   C:\Temp\xxxxxxxxx.tmp

My code works perfectly on localhost when running from the source code and There is no such a folder on web server's directory like mentioned in the message.

My code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FileUploadTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="FileUploadTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1"  Multiple="Multiple" name="okantestfileupload" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnFileUpload" OnClick="btnFileUpload_Clickk" runat="server" Text="ekle" Width="150px" CssClass="CommandButton" />
               <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="ListBoxForInfo" Width="400" CssClass="NormaltextBox" ></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.cs part

```
protected void btnFileUpload_Clickk(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFolder = @"D:\TEST\";
        HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;

        for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadedFile = Request.Files.Get(i);


            var uFileSize = uploadedFile.ContentLength;
            var uFileName = uploadedFile.FileName;
            var uContentType = uploadedFile.ContentType;
            string uExtension =
               System.IO.Path.GetExtension(uploadedFile.FileName);

            uploadedFile.SaveAs(strFolder + uFileName);
            ListBoxForInfo.Items.Insert(0, uFileName + "." + uContentType + " Boyut: (" + uFileSize + " bytes)  yüklendi.");


        }
    }
```

What should I do to fix that?I have already tried some solutions including taking consideration of antivirus programmes.

Regards

Comment: Have you provided write permission to IISUSR for the folder??

Comment: Why are you using `Request.Files` rather than `FileUpload1`? Does the technique shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32731146/34092 or https://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/ work?

Comment: Sorry wrong edit:) Actually I have read all the tutorials and the code works on my local .I am now checking the write permissions on IISUSR but it has a less probability that causes this situation.Because folders are created on the path given on IIS server

Comment: If you use `System.IO.File` to write a text file to `D:\Test\bob.txt` does it succeed?

Comment: @mjwills yes it has been written interestingly

Comment: When you debug the code, what is the **exact** value of `strFolder + uFileName`? `uFileName`?

Comment: the exact value is D:\TEST\file.png (extension is irrelevant at this because all of the files' content become like the statement I mentioned in the question)

Comment: What happens if you use `strFolder = Server.MapPath("");`? If the files are stored correctly then you know you do not have permission to write outside the root folder of the website.

Comment: I have all permissions to users on IIS server even on Everyone user.The files are created very well but contents are corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the Managed Pipeline Mode  configuration of the related Application Pool.The application was run on v2.0 .NET CLR Version but the project was built on .NET 3.5. So changing the Managed **PipeLine** **Mode** from Classic to **Integrated** solved the problem unintentionally without knowing the detailed mechanism. Probable incompatibilities may occur at other external components used in the project.The full cycle test is being performed right now but the upload problem has been **fixed**.

Comment: Good that you were able to solve your issue by yourself; hope you are taking the learning back to check for all relavent configurations and setting before hitting somewhere else. Happy coding, cheers

Comment: It was kinda trial-and-error situation.I assure you that I tried so many methods before the post.Hope somebody can fix their issue faster when they see this solution. happy coding too

Comment: I am getting the same error!
Managed PipeLine Mode is already integrated!
File upload is not working even in Visual Studio!

Answer (score 0):

1. Exclude the folder from project whenever you are building a project.
2. Clean the project
3. Build and deploy again

Comment: Why should I do this?There is no need to exclude any folder from my project

Comment: Please explain _why_ you're suggesting this.

Answer (score 0):

change this folder line  to

string strFolder = @"D:\TEST\";
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/test");
and place the file under  same directory as Website

If Website cannot access d:\test  the file stays in temp folder.